# What does '$' do in R?

Tags: r, integration

I have been trying to understand integration in R and I have come across a code that looks like this:

```
Lambda=function(t) integrate(f=lambda,lower=0,upper=t)$value
```

What does `$value` mean here? What's the '$' sign doing? It's not explained anywhere in the help or on the internet. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?integrate` (bold is mine).

> Value:
>
> A list of class ‘"integrate"’ with components
>
> **value: the final estimate of the integral.**
>
> abs.error: estimate of the modulus of the absolute error.
>
> subdivisions: the number of subintervals produced in the subdivision
>             process.
>
> message: ‘"OK"’ or a character string giving the error message.
>
> call: the matched call.

In other words, `integrate` returns an object of class `"integrate"`, of which element `value` contains the estimate of the integral.

Comment: yes I saw that too but I am struggling to understand how does `$` work? And also, how important is it to call "value" at the end?

Comment: That's very [basic R subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) of `list` elements. The return object of `integrate` is a `list`; you can subset a `list`'s elements with `$name_of_list_element`. Take a look at the `integrate` return object with `str`.

Comment: You're welcome @RTomar